# Mikvah on yom kippur?

Tags: halacha, minhag, yom-kippur, mikvah-ritual-bath

An 'istenis' (delicate) with regards to the mikvah does not want to go, unless absolutely necessary. Is going to the mikvah on Yom Kippur despite this more important, or is he exempt?  Is going to the mikvah on Yom Kippur halacha or minhag?

Comment: Nowadays the generally accepted practice is to forbid going to the Mikva on Yom Kippur.

Comment: Binyamin, a belated welcome to Mi Yodeya.  I've made an edit to your question to generalize it (so it's not just asking about you), and to explicitly ask the halacha-versus-minhag question.  This question should now be in the review queue for possible reopening.  ("On hold" is not meant to be permanent.)  Please feel free to [edit] further if I've misunderstood anything.  Thanks, and I look forward to seeing you around the site.

Comment: He may be referring to the custom of going to the mikva EREV Yom Kippur

Comment: @sam he probably is, but that question would still be off topic

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Even now that it's been depersonalized?